# Is this possible to invoke the method of QGroundControl from a Django(Python) web application?

Tags: python, c++, django, qt-creator, qgroundcontrol

I have a Django web application hosted on Ubuntu 18.04 and on the same machine I have installed the QGroundControl.

In my Django Web Application there are two buttons (**Take Off** & **Return to Land**).

Is this possible that when I press the Take Off button from my Web Application, it should invoke the Take Off method of QGroundControl?

**How can I connect the Django (Python) Web Application & QGroundControl?**

There will be some API or Web Service etc? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I am not using QGroundControl. However, from a quick look at the [doc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20732980/how-to-use-socket-with-a-python-client-and-a-c-server), I think the most straightforward way is to compile your own version of QGroundControl to add a remote control feature. It's open source and the code is available [here](https://github.com/mavlink/qgroundcontrol).

If QGroundControl does not need to be running all the time, you could modify it to accept command-line arguments to request take-off or landing.  These commands could then be launched by Django using the `subprocess` module.

If QGroundControl needs to be running all the time, you could change it to run a socket server, to which you could connect with a Python client, or in your case some Django code.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20732980/how-to-use-socket-with-a-python-client-and-a-c-server) for a (very) minimal example.

If all this looks complex to you, you can always ask QGroundControl developers for a feature request to run a control server with the software.

Comment: Yes, QGroundControl will keep running all the time. I am already compiling my own copy of QGroundControl. This is a lot of information to digest, let me get the details of all the things you mentioned, then I will get back to you. Thanks for your response.